# Where is the reputation tab on MSO

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page

[image: profile]

Where is a reputation tab?

### **EDIT**

> Guys I think i have confused with the names, Please any one post a new answer for difference between **SO** and **SE** and **MSO** and **MSE**.

Comment: You don't earn reputation on a child meta.

Comment: The reputation displayed is your reputation on the main site. So as @juergend says, there is no reputation on the meta site. (Except uniquely for Meta Stack Exchange).

Comment: @juergend , What you mean Child meta? SO where is Parent meta?

Comment: Every Stack Exchange site has its own meta site. And since yesterday there is a new meta site for all sites - http://meta.stackexchange.com/ which was previously MSO.

Comment: @juergend , Now what is the use of up vote and down vote here?

Comment: That has not changed on any meta site - agreement or disagreement. See [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: As well as "good/useful question" or "bad/not researched/not useful question" of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Meta Stack Overflow is the meta site for Stack Overflow. As with *every* (at least now) meta site, reputation is completely inherited from the parent site: Stack Overflow in the case of Meta Stack Overflow.

You cannot earn reputation on a meta site, and the only reputation you have comes from Stack Overflow itself. So if you want a reputation overview, look at your Stack Overflow profile.

#### MSO vs. MSE:

There are many sites on the Stack Exchange network. To manage itself, every site has its own Meta site that discusses things like how to run the site. For example there is [Meta Server Fault](https://meta.serverfault.com/) for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

This has been true for every site, except Stack Overflow. Because SO was the first site of the network, its Meta site, Meta Stack Overflow, has always been served as a general Meta site to not only discuss SO matters, but also general Stack Exchange (the software and the network) stuff. For example technical things that would affect every site.

To solve this problem, the old Meta Stack Overflow was split into the current Meta Stack Overflow, which now works like every other Meta site and is about Stack Overflow alone, and Meta Stack Exchange, which serves the general purpose discussions that apply to every Stack Exchange site.

Meta Stack Exchange is as such a completely separate site. Despite its name (the “Meta”) it is technically not a “Meta” site like the others but instead a standalone site (like Server Fault) which just happens to have “Meta” in its name.

Comment: But why stack exchange web site can earn?

Comment: @RameshRajendran I don’t understand that question…?

Comment: Meta Stack Exchange is a separate site. It is not a child site of any other site. As such, it has reputation. But that is **the only Meta site in the network which has reputation**. That one is different from all the rest @RameshRajendran.

Comment: @poke , But why  [meta stack exchange (MSE)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229821/error-on-the-search-screen#229821)  can earn reputation? but why can't earn reputation on MSO ?

Comment: @Bart So what is the  http://stackexchange.com/ website? and please explain the difference between SE and MSE?

Comment: That site is not a Q&A in itself. It is mostly a landing page to visit the entire network @RameshRajendran.

Comment: @RameshRajendran MSE is a _main_ site, even though we call it 'meta' - notice that it does not have a meta site attached to it. You earn rep on _main_ sites, not child meta sites.

Comment: Guys I think i have confused with the names, Please any one poat a new answer for difference between SO and SE and MSO and MSE.

Comment: I edited it into this perfectly fine answer @RameshRajendran.

Comment: @Bart Now I understood. I think i did't see MSO website in last few days. I think it's a new website?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014 @RameshRajendran, as well as the linked http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212631/stack-overflow-is-getting-a-place-of-its-own

Comment: I added some more stuff on the topic.

Comment: Well, now I clearly understood

Comment: I marked this answer. But it's does not helps to you, bcs the reputation is not change to up. lol :P

Comment: @RameshRajendran It’s not all about reputation. I’m here to help people :)

Comment: @poke Look like SO Supporting  Team :)

Answer (score 5):

Meta StackOverflow is the dedicated meta site for StackOverflow. It does not have its own reputation system, you simply inherit your reputation from StackOverflow.

To quote the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta):

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow (synchronized hourly), though you earn separate badges. You must have 5 reputation to participate on meta.